# I want to extract data from 2 csv files when they match in a specific column but iit is always missing some lines and I dont know why

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 csv files they have one column where it has a code and i want that whenever that code matches the line is extracted from both files and I have tried the code below that works below except for a couple of lines where the code matches when I look for it manually using CTRL+F but it misses those lines somehow.
Is there a way to know why it misses them like the way it reads data maybe or what?

```
import pandas as pd
import os


para_filename = r'D:\PFE\Final_comparing\fichiers_base_grossistes\para-bapharma.csv'
para_df = pd.read_csv(para_filename)


converted_filename = r'D:\PFE\Final_comparing\fichiers_ventes\I660124N.csv'
converted_df = pd.read_csv(converted_filename)

matching_df = pd.merge(para_df, converted_df, left_on='code', right_on='code produit', how='left')

matched_names_df = matching_df[['name', 'nom de produit']].drop_duplicates()


matched_names_df = matched_names_df[matched_names_df['nom de produit'].notna()]


matched_names_grouped_df = matched_names_df.groupby('name')['nom de produit'].agg(lambda x: '; '.join(x)).reset_index()


matched_output_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(para_filename))[0] + "_matched_" + os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(converted_filename))[0] + ".csv"
med_names_output_filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(converted_filename))[0] + "_med_names.csv"


matched_names_grouped_df.to_csv(matched_output_filename, index=False)


med_names_df = converted_df['nom de produit'].drop_duplicates()


med_names_df.to_csv(med_names_output_filename, index=False)

print(f"Files '{matched_output_filename}' and '{med_names_output_filename}' have been generated.")
```

These are the first 5 lines of each csv file for reference:
I660124N.csv:

```
code grossiste,code produit,lettre,code postal,unite vendu,nom de produit,prix

50066,303107,B,1000,00000003,FOSALEN D3 BTE 12,00000.000
50066,303107,B,1003,00000002,FOSALEN D3 BTE 12,00000.000
50066,303107,B,1004,00000002,FOSALEN D3 BTE 12,00000.000
50066,303107,B,2041,00000002,FOSALEN D3 BTE 12,00000.000 

para-bapharma.csv:

code,name

644018,AD.EXOMEGA LAIT 400ML     
649595,AD.PAIN AU LAIT D'AVOINE  
31,ADOLOR   GEL

AD04,ADOLOR FORT BT30
```

Comment: You most likely want to perform an inner merge.